# Calendar Widget not working? Using Date classes and Object-Oriented JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, object, time, widget

I'm taking a college course on JavaScript and am trying to follow one of the Chapter Hands-On Activites (using the textbook JavaScript: The Web Warrior Series By Sasha Vodnik and Don Gosselin in Chapter 7). It's supposed to create a calendar widget which isn't showing up. My end goal is to show the time elapsed from the date entered by the user.

This is the code provided in the textbook. I've copied it as exactly as is, double checked for errors, and used debugging tools. Google Chrome developer tools doesn't indicate any errors.

JS Code:

```
var dateObject = new Date();

function displayCalendar(whichMonth) {
var dateObject =  new Date();
var date;
var dateToday = newDate();
var dayOfWeek;
var daysInMonth;
var dateCells;
var captionValue;
var month;
var year;
var monthArray = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "Decemeber"];
if (whichMonth === -1) {
    dateObject.setMonth(dateObject.getMonth() - 1);
} else if (whichMonth === 1) {
    dateObject.setMonth(dateObject.getMonth() + 1);
}

month = dateObject.getMonth();
year = dateObject.getFullYear();
dateObject.setDate(1);
dayOfWeek = dateObject.getDay();
captionValue = monthArray[month] + " " + year;
document.querySelector("#cal table caption").innerHTML = captionValue;

if(month === 0 || month === 2 || month === 4 || month === 6 || month === 7 || month === 9 || month === 11) { // Jan, Mar, May, Jul, Aug, Oct, Dec
    daysInMonth = 31;
} else if (month === 1) { // Feb
    if (year % 4 === 0) { //leap year test
        if (year % 100 === 0) {
            // year ending in 00 not a leap year unless
            // divisible by 400
            if (year % 400 === 0) {
                daysInMonth = 29;
            } else {
                daysInMonth = 28;
            }
        } else {
            daysInMonth = 29;
        }
    } else {
        daysInMonth = 28;
    }
} else { //Apr, Jun, Sep, Nov
    daysInMonth = 30;
}

dateCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < dateCells.length; i++) {
    // clear existing table dates
    dateCells[i].innerHTML = "";
    dateCells[i].className = "";
}

for (var i = dayOfWeek; i < daysInMonth + dayOfWeek; i++) {
    // add dates to days cells
    dateCells[i].innerHTML = dateObject.getDate();
    dateCells[i].className = "date";
    if (dateToday < dateObject) {
        dateCells[i].className = "futuredate";
    }
    date = dateObject.getDate() + 1;
    dateObject.setDate(date);

    dateObject.setMonth(dateObject.getMonth() -1);
    // reset month to month shown
    document.getElementById("cal").style.display = "block";
    // display calendar if it's not already visible
}

function selectDate(event) {
    if (event === undefined) { //get caller element in IE8
        event = window.event;
    }
    var callerElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
if (callerElement.innerHTML === "") {
    //cell contains no date, so don't close the calendar
    document.getElementById("cal").style.display = "block";
    return false;
}
dateObject.setDate(callerElement.innerHTML);

var fullDateToday = new Date();
var dateToday = Date.UTC(fullDateToday.getFullYear(), fullDateToday.getMonth(), dateObject.getDate());
if (selectedDate <= dateToday) {
    document.getElementById("cal").style.display = "block";
    return false;
}
document.getElementById("tripDate").value = dateObject.toLocaleDateString();
}


function CreateEventListeners() {
    var dateField = document.getElementById("tripDate");
        if (dateField.addEventListener) {
            dateField.addEventListener("click", displayCalendar, false);
        } else if (dateField.attachEvent) {
            dateField.attachEvent("onclick", displayCalendar);
        }

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", createEventListeners, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListeners);
}
    var dateCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    if (dateCells[0].addEventListener) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dateCells.length; i++) {
            dateCells[i].addEventListener("click", selectDate, false);
        }
    } else if (dateCells[0].attachEvent) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dateCells.length; i++) {
            dateCells[i].attachEvent("onclick", selectDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there's a missing `}` - you also have two redundant re-declarations of `var i`

Comment: can you show your HTML, and how you try to execute this code

Comment: you have a function called `CreateEventListeners` ... which you seem to want to call using `window.addEventListener("load", createEventListeners, false);` ... which of course wont work because that's not the same name

Comment: These are errors I've found by a "cursory glance" - but as a bonus ... here's a simpler way to get `daysInMonth` ... `daysInMonth = new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();` (yes, month+1 is not a mistake) - I've just saved you 33 lines of code :p

Comment: `dateObject.setMonth(dateObject.getMonth() - 1);` why are you subtracting a month for every iteration? `This is the code provided in the textbook` - throw it in a fire, it is garbage

Comment: `var dateToday = newDate();` or `var dateToday = new Date();` ?